# orgmode: link to id doesn't work

Tags: org-mode

I create the id of the heading (with `org-id-copy` function) and somewhere in the file i create link to it: `[[id:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX][name]]`. The problem is that the link works only on the computer i created it. When i move the file to another computer, the link stops working, giving the error:
`No match - create this as new heading? (y/n)`

How can i make it work on another computer? Is there any function to scan all ids and make links work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the answer for your specific question. But alternatively using `org-store-link` (I bind it to `C-c l`) to store the link to the heading and then insert the link with `org-insert-link` (I bind it to `C-c C-l`) will do what you want, since `org-store-link` will make a link containing the location of the `org` file.

If you want to be able to change the heading names freely, then you can add `CUSTOM_ID` property to the target heading and generate a link to it (for example, `[[#my_casutom_id]]`). Then you can freely change the heading itself without breaking the link.

Comment: There's one problem with this solution - when my headings change names, the links stop working completely. That's why i want to use ```org-id-copy```. If it only was working on different computers too (i'm syncing my org file with 2 computers).

Comment: No, at least by default (?), when using the above key bindings, Org creates a PROPERTY with a hash at the target headline, and then insert a link with the same hash where you wanna put your links.

Comment: What property name is added when you use it ```org-store-link```? I have the same keybindings, but for me the functions only copy/paste the name of the heading, not any properties.

Comment: You can add `CUSTOM_ID` property and generate a link to it as well. Then you can freely change the heading itself without breaking the link.

Comment: @joon this is the solution, i used CUSTOM_ID property and link in the format [[#my_custom_id]] and it works across different computers. Can you post it as an answer so i can mark it as solution? Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome - I'm glad it worked out for you. I just added `CUSTOM_ID` part to this answer so you can make it as solution.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer `org-id` solution over `CUSTOM_ID` property.

To have it working across multiple machines you simply need to run `org-id-update-id-locations` after moving your file to another machine!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The `CUSTOM_ID` approach will fail in certain circumstances, e.g. after archiving. Also the ids are stored in a file specified by the `org-id-locations-file` variable, and the default is `~/.emacs.d/.org-id-locations`, so it's a hidden file.

Answer (score 1):

The `org-id` file associations are stored in `org-id-locations-file`. You should be able to refresh them using [`org-id-update-id-locations`](https://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-id-update-id-locations), which will rescan

> all agenda files, all associated archives, all open Org
> files, and all files currently mentioned in `org-id-locations`.

You can also call it with a list of org-mode files as an argument and it will scan those too.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error when navigating to a link but fixed it by explicitly loading org-id: `(require 'org-id)`